# Retrieve FULL string from SQL Server Column in WPF Application

Tags: sql-server, wpf

I was not sure to pose this question (So I will edit if needed).

Basically, I have a **WPF Application**. In the application is a **DataGrid** that is bound to a **SQL Table** (through a **Dataset**).

One of the columns in this table is a 'notes' column, which I created for the purpose of adding/removing text that could or could not be very long.

I then discovered the amount of characters that is retrieved from the column is only 50 (There is a TextBox here bound to that specific column to show the data in it) - So only up to 50 characters of text was displayed in the TextBox.

After a bit of reading I found that the Column Data Type (which is currently **VARCHAR**), was set to **VARCHAR(50)** - This made sense.

I then changed the Data Type to **VARCHAR(MAX)**, updated the Dataset (which reflected the change) and tried again - I get the same result even though the Length property of the column has been set to its maximum.

I have tried other Data Types for this column such as **TEXT** & **NVARCHAR(MAX)** - result renamed the same.

I even looked at the Length property of the TextBox, and this seemed ok (Was set to 0 by default, so I changed it to 100 - no change in behavior).

I am literally stumped. Is it supposed to be this way? Am I missing something? I would really appreciate some insight.

**[UPDATE]:**

So I played around a bit with it. I decided to update the column in SSMS with a very long string. I then pulled this column with DATALENGTH(column_name) and the entire string was there with a length of 272.

I then checked this in the application. The entire string was returned. Added a few more chars to see what happens.

Not only was the extra chars not added, the entire string was truncated to a length of 100. Checked in SSMS as well, same result.

Now I am even more lost than I was before. But at least I know the problem isn't with the table or column data type & length.

**[How I am reading/writing the data]:**

My WPF application has a DataGrid. This DataGrid is bound to a Dataset configured from the SQL Database.

When I double a row in the DataGrid, a new Window is opened and the textboxes/comboboxes is populated with the selected row's data.

In the (New) Window_Loaded event, I reference the DataGrid in question.

```
Private Sub Window_Loaded(sender as Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim mainWindow = TryCast(Application.Current.Windows.Cast(of Window)().FirstOrDefault(Function(EditAsset) TypeOf EditAsset Is MainWindow), MainWindow)
    Dim dgMainWindow As DataGrid = MainWindow.AssetsDataGrid
    Dim row as Data.DataRowView = DirectCast(dgMainWindow.SelectedItems(0), Data.DataRowView)
    Dim SelectedAssetTableAdapter As retailassetdbDatasetTableAdapters.tableAssetsTableAdapter = New retailassetdbTableAdapters.tableAssetsTableAdapter()
    Dim SelectedAssetDataTable As New retailassetdbDataset.tableAssetsDataTable

    SelectedAssetTableAdapter.FillBySelectedItem(SelectedAssetDataTable, row("Id"), row("assetSerial")

    txtAsseetNotes.Text = SelectedAssetDataTable.Rows.Item(0)("assetNotes")
End Sub
```

As a result, the TextBox displays the information of the Asset Notes column.

**[Saving to the Database]:**

The Dataset has an update query to update a particular entry (based on id & serial gotten from DataGrid).

```
Private Sub btnSaveChanges(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim SelectedAssetTableAdapter As retailassetdbDatasetTableAdapters.tableAssetsTableAdapter = New retailassetdbTableAdapters.tableAssetsTableAdapter()
    Dim SelectedAssetDataTable As New retailassetdbDataset.tableAssetsDataTable
    SelectedAssetTableAdapter.UpdateAsset(txtAssetNotes.Text, assetSerial, assetID)
End Sub
```

This saves the data back to the database.

**[EDIT]:**

Here are some pictures of the properties of:

1. The TextBox
2. The Column in the Table
3. The Column in the Dataset

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the full string actually coming back in you data layer? How are you accessing this data? There might be another size somewhere else such as in an output parameter etc.

Comment: I am accessing the data through the WPF application. As mentioned above, there is a TextBox that is bound to that specific column in the table.   When I reduce the string, it saves back to the table and when I read it again it comes up with what was saved. But as soon as it exceeds that 50 length mark it cuts off. How/Where would I check what the value is in the data layer?

Comment: See my update after some testing.

Comment: You havn't detailed how you are reading/writing the data to SQL. Entity framework, SQL command, Stored Procedure,  carrier pigeon, what?

Comment: Are you saying that you added a string consisting of 272 chars and it worked in SSMS. Then you ran your application and afterwards the string is truncated to 100 chars even when you retrieve it in SSMS?

Comment: apc, I added some code to explain how i read/write the data. Does that help? @Jonny, partly right. Adding the string in SSMS saves the entire string. Reading it from the application (1st time) reads entire string. Editing the string truncates it to 100.

Comment: I think the problem is clear, you inserted the data with 272, but your `textbox` now has a limit of 100 chars,so `textbox` will truncate that to 100chars, when you update, the new string of 100 chars get updated in database.

Comment: @MathewJibin, that makes sense. But, currently the TextBox MaxLength property is set to 2147483647. I only changed it to a 100 to test (as it was 0 by default), but changed it to 2147483647 afterwards.

Comment: after changing those values, it wont magically retrieve lost data from somewhere, you need to update the database with new value to see if it works. Your database is not hiding data, it only has that much data to begin with. :)

Comment: @MathewJibin, that's exactly what I did (and what I've been doing). The result remains the same. Update the data with a LONG string. Read the string from the table in app - full string retrieved. Edit string by removing 1 char - when reading it again it's been truncated to 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I am feeling like a complete idiot at the moment.

After thinking I have been thorough in trying to determine WHERE the problem lies, I overlooked 1 thing:

THE UPDATE STATEMENT OF THE DATASET!

Even I reconfigured the Dataset with the new properties of the database/table, I left Update Statement as is. So I am thinking the old Update statement was referencing old parameters when doing the update?

Anyway, I created a Test Update Statement on the newly configured Dataset and tried it out. It works!

Thanks to all for the replies.